# How do I change the color ls in the console for files if group owner is `root`?

Tags: colors, root, ls

I am inside a mounted folder: `/mnt/hgfs` because of this all the files' owner is `root`.

In this folder when I do `ls` color for all the files show up as green and for all the folders, there is green highlight. Is it possible to use default color of `ls`: which is:

```
❯ echo $LS_COLORS
rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
```

Default color under home directory:
[image]

---

Color under the `mnt` directory:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the green highlighting is because your directories are writable by other (`o+w`) and not sticky.

To remove it, meaning make it look like normal directories, append the
following to `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:ow=1;34:tw=1;34:"
```

Save and run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

`ow` stands for "other, writable", `tw` is "sticky, writable"
(the other condition that has a green background).
The color code has 3 columns (unused columns are left out):

```
bold;font-color;bg-color
```

References:

- [What do the different colors mean in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal)
- [How do I change the color for directories with ls in the console?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console)
- [Ugly color for directories in gnome- terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881949/ugly-color-for-directories-in-gnome-terminal)
- [Wikipedia Sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)

Comment: What is meant by `sticky`  ?

Comment: See Wikipedia [Sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) for the complete story.

Comment: Sorry for a late comment, would it be possible to change colors for file as well? For example I have applied (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322032/198423) to make color changes on specific files but they do not apply if I am inside a folder , where its owner is`root`?

Answer (score 0):

So, I can assume that you are on a mac because you are referencing the `LSCOLORS` variable and not `LS_COLORS`.  Is this correct?  macOS/BSD colors and Linux colors are DIFFERENT!.. You should add that tag to your question.

Simple answer.  You can't do this without processing all of the output of `ls` yourself.

Here is a list of the attributes that can be affected by LSCOLORS:

- directory
- symbolic link
- socket
- pipe
- executable
- block special
- character special
- executable with setuid bit set
- executable with setgid bit set
- directory writable to others, with sticky bit
- directory writable to others, without sticky bit

***THATS IT!***  *Unless one of these attributes will solve your problem*, any more processing would need to be handled by wrapping  the `ls` command and customizing the ANSI colors yourself.

BTW, I found this SUPER COOL `LSCOLORS` and `LS_COLORS` generator on the web making coloring the prompt SUPER EASY!

https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/

Comment: I am actually on Linux updated the question with my `LS_COLORS` variable. Actally coloring works fine for the main user but especially if the group owner is `root` colors become green.

Comment: Basically I am using multiple VM in VMware and generated a shared forder for each ofther where I was thinking to develop my code; same directory for all. But I realized since the shared folder it mounted under `/mnt` group owner for all the files and folders is root which leads `ls` to have green color

Comment: bummer but neither of those things changes what LS_COLORS will or won't do.  I am glad you found a workaround.  Linux has a few more options than BSD (no surprise there) but as you can see [here](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors) there still isn't the option you want and I personally wish was in there :)  It sure would be nice to have more options.

Comment: That's the problem I was not able to find a workaround :-) I mean I customize `LS_COLORS` but my setup does not have any affect if the group owner is `root`